# Writing ASP.NET frameworks other than WebForms or MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I want to know what "clean" ASP.NET looks like. For example, I want to build my own framework on ASP.NET, and I don't know what assembly I should include.

All books discussing ASP.NET describe either WebForms or MVC, but none explain the ASP.NET layer of things.

What part of ASP.NET is meant in below picture?

[image: img]

Comment: Probably you ment [ASP.net Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

Comment: @Stefan Kert. Definitely no. It was community framework, not Microsoft.

Comment: NancyFx is such an example of one, Fubu MVC is another.

Comment: I've edited your question so it isn't off-topic. You can't ask for frameworks or books, see [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both WebForms and MVC are implemented through a handler, see the [ASP.NET Page Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) and [MvcHandler Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler(v=vs.118).aspx) on MSDN.

[Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) ([MSDN: Introduction to HTTP Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(v=vs.100).aspx)) are the most lightweight way to utilize ASP.NET. You get access to an [HttpRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) instance that knows everything about the request there is to know.

In a handler, you read this HttpRequest, apply your application logic and write the result throught the HttpResponse member instance that an [IHttpHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter in [ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) has:

```
namespace HandlerExample
{
   public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
      // Override the ProcessRequest method.
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
         context.Response.Write("<H1>This is an HttpHandler Test.</H1>");      
         context.Response.Write("<p>Your Browser:</p>");
         context.Response.Write("Type: " + context.Request.Browser.Type + "<br>");
         context.Response.Write("Version: " + context.Request.Browser.Version);
      }

      // Override the IsReusable property.
      public bool IsReusable
      {
         get { return true; }
      }
   }
}
```

A lot of ASP.NET, if not all, lives in the System.Web namespace.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET WebForms and MVC are built on top of the ASP.NET engine, which basically consists of modules, handlers, and the ecosystem around that.

In fact you can write your own framework by writing modules and handlers. You can write your own code that picks up the request and handles it (handler) or adjust existing messages (modules).

Comment: Can you provide some starting point for discovering "ASP.NET engine"?
I would be appreciative

Comment: I often used this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) and its references.

Answer (score 2):

We used [NancyFX](http://nancyfx.org/) in several projects and it's definitely worth looking into. Simplicity and performance are amazing. You can host it independently or over the IIS (like asp.net). And it's also cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks. It is what I am looking for. But I can't mark your answer as right because question was edited by admin.